# Chrome RGBA issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to set background color for an element using `jQuery('.element').css('background-color', 'rgba(183, 56, 56, 0.43)');` but calling `jQuery('.element').css('background-color');` right after that returns `rgba(183, 56, 56, 0.431373)` in Chrome 33.0.1750.154 m. It seems to work in Firefox 28.0 though.

Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/y3H3n/

Does anyone know why this happens and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Why is it a bug? I can't imagine the precision really matters to you, so how is it negatively affecting your code?

Comment: @cookiemonster Users type in `0.43` in a form field to set alpha and after they deselect it it gets updated to `0.431373`. They are confused. So am I.

Comment: I can't imagine a `0.001373` difference would cause all that much confusion, but if you want it exactly the same, then parse the alpha out, and truncate anything beyond 2 places to the right of the decimal. I think some browsers may also remove the space after the `,` so I guess that could confuse people too?

Comment: @cookiemonster I don't understand why are you so full of contempt to my question. Technically it doesn't make much difference but imagine that you deposited `$4300` in a bank and right after doing so you would unexpectedly have `$4275`. Wouldn't you be puzzled and wouldn't you seek some explanation? Good UI/UX designers would never allow such inconsistencies to occur (yes, even with the space and `,`). Those are psychological, not technical matters.

Comment: I don't understand why you've taken my comments as contemptuous. I just don't see any cause for confusion. But if you think it's a problem, then change its formatting. That's all I'm saying. Must say though that your banking analogy is nuts. If I found out my statement was off by slightly more than one-tenth  of a penny in my favor, I'd not give it a second thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.431373 is, as near as makes no difference, 110/255. Colours are 32-bit, with 8 bits assigned to the Alpha channel. This means that, strictly speaking, it is on a scale from 0 to 255. It's just that, for some reason, we express alpha as a float.

Comment: So Chrome doesn't actually react to `0.43`? It only knows about `109/255` and `110/255` - `0.4275` and `0.431373` respectively? It just rounded my value? That makes sense. Firefox rounds it too but just keeps displaying it as `0.43`?

Comment: @Jimsea Actually, testing on Chrome, on devtools it is still displayed as `0.43` on the styles tab, but calling by JS returns `0.431373`

Comment: @RaphaelDDL I didn't know that alpha is on a scale 0 to 255. That's why I thought that it's a bug (and I entitled my question incorrectly it seems) but it's not. Everything's clear now. I should probably use a different scale for my input field then (not from 0 to 1 with 0.01 step but from 0 to 255). Chrome is most likely using `0.43` in styles tab to not confuse people. I was checking it with JavaScript thought so it returned correctly rounded value for me and not the one I typed in. Thank you both!